# a Php function serving random values from an array

Tags: php, function

```
function acids(){
    $acidsarray=array('lemonjuice','vinegar','sherry','champagne','orange');
    $acids=array_rand($acidsarray);
    echo $acids;
}
```

Hello, I'm new to programming and this is a function I've written, the idea is it's supposed to spit out one of the ingredients from the array; when I run it it returns a number, usually between 0 and 4, so it's doing something though not what I want it to do. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

I've written the function in python, using the same logic and it works fine.

Thank you

Comment: It's always good to read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_rand` returns the key only, so when you echo you'd need to instead echo:

```
echo $acidsarray[$acids];
```

Comment: Right, so in Php lingo i need to go a step further and hook the random picker to the actual array.

Comment: Yeah, basically it returns an identifier rather than the data

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the following:

```
function acids(){
            $acidsarray=array('lemonjuice','vinegar','sherry','champagne','orange');
            $acids=$acidsarray[array_rand($acidsarray)];
            echo $acids;
}
```

Because the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) say

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and **returns the key (or keys) of the random entries**.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd read the documentation, you'd have seen [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns a random index valid for subsequently using on the array.

So you'll need to add:

```
$acids = $acidsarray[$acids];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shuffle function to serve random value.

```
function acids(){
    $acidsarray = array('lemonjuice','vinegar','sherry','champagne','orange');
    shuffle($acidsarray);
    echo $acidsarray[0];
}
```

Comment: might come in handy someday :)